# Getting a null return value from my Map when the defined object exists in the map already?

Tags: java, functional-programming

Essentially on line 331 of Player, I am getting a Null Pointer Exception Error due to the Functional Map returning a Null Value instead of the intended Integer[]. This is the player object in a game.

I have tried every way I can think of and nothing seems to work, I am not sure on the issue even, and how to fix it.

```
package Default;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

import Default.Equipment;
import Default.EquipmentType;

public class Player implements PlayerObjectInterface
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Class Variables
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    EquipmentMap EquipmentList;
    public enum CharacterClass{
        Warrior, Crusader, Rogue, Paladin};

    //00 01 02 03 04     01 02 03 04 05
    private String szCharacterName;
    private CharacterClass eCharacterClass;
    private Equipment[] myEquipment;
    private int iExperience;
    private int[] iIVs;
    private int iCurrentHitpoints;
    //private Inventory




    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //default
    public Player()
    {
        myEquipment = new Equipment[5];
        iIVs = new int[3];
        EquipmentList = new EquipmentMap();

        reset();

        return;
    }

    //creating new Player at game start
    public Player(String CharacterName, CharacterClass CharacterClass)
    {
        myEquipment = new Equipment[5];
        iIVs = new int[3];
        EquipmentList = new EquipmentMap();

        reset();

        setCharacterName(CharacterName);
        setCharacterClass(CharacterClass);

        return;
    }

    //loading Player from file

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Setters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setCharacterName(String CharacterName)
    {
        this.szCharacterName = CharacterName; 
        return;
    }

    public void setCharacterClass(CharacterClass Class) 
    {
        this.eCharacterClass = Class;
        return;
    }

    public void setMyEquipment(EquipmentType equipmentType, ItemType Item) 
    {
        this.myEquipment[ equipmentType.getValue() ] .setItem(Item) ;
        return;
    }

    public void setExperience(int Experience) 
    {
        this.iExperience = Experience;
        return;
    }

    private void setIV(IVType IVType, int IV)
    {
        this.iIVs[ IVType.getValue() ] = IV;
        return;
    }

    private void setCurrentHitpoints(int CurrentHitpoints)
    {
        this.iCurrentHitpoints = CurrentHitpoints;
        if(getCurrentHitpoints() < 0)
        {
            setCurrentHitpoints(0);
        }

        return;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Getters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getCharacterName()
    {
        return(this.szCharacterName);
    }

    public CharacterClass getCharacterClass() 
    {
        return(this.eCharacterClass);
    }

    public ItemType getMyEquipment(EquipmentType equipmentType) 
    {
        return( (this.myEquipment[ equipmentType.getValue() ].getItem()) );
    }

    public int getExperience() 
    {
        return(this.iExperience);
    }

    public int getIV(BaseStatType BaseStatType)
    {
        return(this.iIVs[ BaseStatType.getValue() ]);
    }

    private int getCurrentHitpoints()
    {
        return(this.iCurrentHitpoints);
    }
    private int getLevel()
    {
        int iLevel = 5;
        int iExperience = getExperience();

        iLevel = (int) java.lang.Math.floor( ( Math.pow( iExperience,-3 ) / 1.25 )  );
        if( iLevel > 100 )
        {
            iLevel = 100;
        }
        return (iLevel);
    }

    private int getBaseStat(BaseStatType eBaseStatType)
    {
        int[] iWarriorBaseStats = {60,100,80};
        int[] iCrusaderBaseStats = {80,60,100};
        int[] iPaladinBaseStats = {60,80,100};
        int[] iRogueBaseStats = {100,80,60};
        int[] iDefaultBaseStats = {60,60,60};
        int iBaseStat = 60;
        CharacterClass eClass = getCharacterClass();

        switch(eClass)
        {
            case Warrior:
            iBaseStat = iWarriorBaseStats[ eBaseStatType.getValue() ];
            break;

            case Crusader:
            iBaseStat = iCrusaderBaseStats[ eBaseStatType.getValue() ];         
            break;

            case Paladin:
            iBaseStat = iPaladinBaseStats[ eBaseStatType.getValue() ];
            break;

            case Rogue:
            iBaseStat = iRogueBaseStats[ eBaseStatType.getValue() ];
            break;

            default:
            iBaseStat = iDefaultBaseStats[ eBaseStatType.getValue() ];          
            break;
        }

        return (iBaseStat);
    }

    public int getStat(StatType eStatType)
    {
        int iStat = 0;
        int iBaseStat = 60;
        int iLevel = getLevel();
        int iIV = 0;

        switch(eStatType)
        {
            case Attack:
            iBaseStat = getBaseStat(BaseStatType.Strength);
            iIV = getIV(BaseStatType.Strength);
            break;

            case Defence:
            iBaseStat = getBaseStat(BaseStatType.Protection);
            iIV = getIV(BaseStatType.Protection);
            break;

            case Hitpoints:
            iBaseStat = getBaseStat(BaseStatType.Vitality);
            iIV = getIV(BaseStatType.Vitality);
            break;

            default:
            iBaseStat = 60;
            iIV = 0;
            break;
        }

        if (eStatType == StatType.Hitpoints)
        {
            iStat = ( ( ( ( ( 2 * iBaseStat ) + iIV ) 
                    * iLevel ) / 100 ) + iLevel + 10);
        }
        else
        {
            iStat = ( ( ( ( ( 2 * iBaseStat) + iIV ) 
                    * iLevel ) / 100 ) + 5);
        }

        return(iStat);
    }

    private double getModifier()
    {
        Random RandomModifier = new Random();
        int iRandom1 = 0;
        int iRandom2 = 0;
        int iMinimumRandom = 0;
        int iMaximumRandom = 0;

        double dModifier = 1;
        double dCriticalModifier = 1;
        double dRandomModifier = 1;

        Integer iSwordStats[] = EquipmentList.getObject(myEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Sword).getValue() ]);
        int iCritChance = 5 + iSwordStats[ (WeaponStatType.CritChance.getValue()) ];

        iMinimumRandom = 1;
        iMaximumRandom = 100;
        iRandom1 = (RandomModifier.nextInt
                ( (iMaximumRandom - iMinimumRandom) + 1 )
                + iMinimumRandom );
        if( iRandom1 <= iCritChance )
        {
            dCriticalModifier = 1.75;
        }
        else
        {
            dCriticalModifier = 1;
        }

        iMinimumRandom = 85;
        iMaximumRandom = 100;
        iRandom2 = (RandomModifier.nextInt
                ( (iMaximumRandom - iMinimumRandom) + 1 )
                + iMinimumRandom );
        dRandomModifier = iRandom2 / 100;

        dModifier = dCriticalModifier * dRandomModifier;
        return (dModifier);

    }

    public int getPlayerAttack()
    {
        int iPlayerAttack;
        Integer iSwordStats[] = EquipmentList.getObject(myEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Sword).getValue() ]);

        iPlayerAttack = getStat(StatType.Attack) 
                + iSwordStats[ (WeaponStatType.Power).getValue() ];

        return(iPlayerAttack);
    }

    public int getPlayerDefence()
    {
        int iPlayerDefence;
        Integer iHelmetStats[] = EquipmentList.getObject(myEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Helmet).getValue() ]);
        Integer iChestplateStats[] = EquipmentList.getObject(myEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Chestplate).getValue() ]);
        Integer iLeggingsStats[] = EquipmentList.getObject(myEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Leggings).getValue() ]);
        Integer iBootsStats[] = EquipmentList.getObject(myEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Boots).getValue() ]);

        iPlayerDefence = getStat(StatType.Defence) 
                + iHelmetStats[ (ArmourStatType.Power).getValue() ]
                + iChestplateStats[ (ArmourStatType.Power).getValue() ] 
                + iLeggingsStats[ (ArmourStatType.Power).getValue() ]
                + iBootsStats[ (ArmourStatType.Power).getValue() ];

        return(iPlayerDefence);
    }

    public int getPlayerHitpoints()
    {
        int iPlayerHitpoints = 0;
        Integer[] iHelmetStats = new Integer[2];
        Integer[] iChestplateStats = new Integer[2];
        Integer[] iLeggingsStats = new Integer[2];
        Integer[] iBootsStats = new Integer[2];

        Equipment[] eMyEquipment = new Equipment[5];

        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Sword) );
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Helmet) );
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate) );
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Leggings) );
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Boots) );

        iHelmetStats = EquipmentList.getObject( eMyEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Helmet).getValue() ]);
        iChestplateStats = EquipmentList.getObject( eMyEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Chestplate).getValue() ]);
        iLeggingsStats = EquipmentList.getObject( eMyEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Leggings).getValue() ]);
        iBootsStats = EquipmentList.getObject( eMyEquipment[ (EquipmentType.Boots).getValue() ]);

        iPlayerHitpoints = getStat(StatType.Hitpoints) 
                + iHelmetStats[ (ArmourStatType.Hitpoints).getValue() ]
                + iChestplateStats[ (ArmourStatType.Hitpoints).getValue() ] 
                + iLeggingsStats[ (ArmourStatType.Hitpoints).getValue() ]
                + iBootsStats[ (ArmourStatType.Hitpoints).getValue() ];

        return(iPlayerHitpoints);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Utilities
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void addExperience(int Experience)
    {
        int iLevelBefore = getLevel();
        int iLevelAfter = 0;
        setExperience( (getExperience() + Experience) );
        iLevelAfter = getLevel();

        if(iLevelBefore < iLevelAfter)
        {
            System.out.println("You leveled up to Level " + iLevelAfter);
        }

        return;

    }

    public boolean isPlayerDead()
    {
        if(getCurrentHitpoints() == 0)
        {
            return(true);
        }
        return(false);
    }

    public int calculatePlayerDamage(int iEnemyDefence)
    {
        double dDamage = 0;
        int iDamage = 0;
        int iPlayerAttack = getPlayerAttack();
        int iLevel = getLevel();
        double dModifier = getModifier();

        //finish calculation
        dDamage = (((((( 2 * iLevel) / 5 ) * (iPlayerAttack / iEnemyDefence ) ) / 50 ) + 2) * dModifier);
        iDamage = (int) java.lang.Math.floor(dDamage);

        return(iDamage);
    }

    public void displayObject()
    {
        System.out.println("CharacterName = " + getCharacterName());
        System.out.println("Class = " + getCharacterClass());
        System.out.println("Equipment (Sword) = " + getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Sword));
        System.out.println("Equipment (Helmet) = " + getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Helmet));
        System.out.println("Equipment (Chestplate) = " + getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate));
        System.out.println("Equipment (Leggings) = " + getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Leggings));
        System.out.println("Equipment (Boots) = " + getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Boots));
        System.out.println("Experience = " + getExperience());
        System.out.println("Strength IV = " + getIV(BaseStatType.Strength));
        System.out.println("Defence IV = " + getIV(BaseStatType.Protection));
        System.out.println("Vitality IV = " + getIV(BaseStatType.Vitality));
        System.out.println("Attack = " + getPlayerAttack());
        System.out.println("Defence = " + getPlayerDefence());
        System.out.println("Hitpoints = " + getCurrentHitpoints() + "/" + getPlayerHitpoints());

        //class equipment  experience IV hitpoints
    }

    private void reset()
    {
        Random RandomIV = new Random();
        int iMinimumIV = 0;
        int iMaximumIV = 31;

        setCharacterName("A");
        setCharacterClass(CharacterClass.Warrior);

        this.myEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword , ItemType.Beginner_Sword);
        this.myEquipment[1] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet , ItemType.Beginner_Helmet);
        this.myEquipment[2] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate , ItemType.Beginner_Chestplate);
        this.myEquipment[3] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings , ItemType.Beginner_Leggings);
        this.myEquipment[4] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots , ItemType.Beginner_Boots);

        setExperience(3907);

        setIV( (IVType.Strength), RandomIV.nextInt
                ( (iMaximumIV - iMinimumIV) + 1 ) 
                + iMinimumIV);
        setIV( (IVType.Protection), RandomIV.nextInt
                ( (iMaximumIV - iMinimumIV) + 1 ) 
                + iMinimumIV);
        setIV( (IVType.Vitality), RandomIV.nextInt
                ( (iMaximumIV - iMinimumIV) + 1 ) 
                + iMinimumIV);

        populateEquipmentMap();

        setCurrentHitpoints(getPlayerHitpoints());
    }

    private void populateEquipmentMap() 
    {
        Integer[][] passingvalues = 
                    {
                            {15,0},{35,8},{75,16},{110,25},{150,32},{185,40},
                            {10,16},{22,35},{47,72},{69,107},{94,144},{116,182},
                            {15,25},{35,55},{75,115},{110,170},{150,230},{185,290},
                            {14,22},{31,49},{49,101},{97,149},{132,202},{162,254},
                            {8,13},{18,28},{38,58},{55,85},{75,115},{93,145}
                    };

        Equipment[] myEquipment = new Equipment[30];

        myEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword, ItemType.Beginner_Sword);
        myEquipment[1] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword, ItemType.Cloth_Sword);
        myEquipment[2] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword, ItemType.Wooden_Sword);
        myEquipment[3] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword, ItemType.Iron_Sword);
        myEquipment[4] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword, ItemType.Frost_Sword);
        myEquipment[5] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword, ItemType.Magma_Sword);

        myEquipment[6] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet, ItemType.Beginner_Helmet);
        myEquipment[7] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet, ItemType.Cloth_Helmet);
        myEquipment[8] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet, ItemType.Wooden_Helmet);
        myEquipment[9] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet, ItemType.Iron_Helmet);
        myEquipment[10] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet, ItemType.Frost_Helmet);
        myEquipment[11] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet, ItemType.Magma_Helmet);

        myEquipment[12] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate, ItemType.Beginner_Chestplate);
        myEquipment[13] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate, ItemType.Cloth_Chestplate);
        myEquipment[14] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate, ItemType.Wooden_Chestplate);
        myEquipment[15] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate, ItemType.Iron_Chestplate);
        myEquipment[16] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate, ItemType.Frost_Chestplate);
        myEquipment[17] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate, ItemType.Magma_Chestplate);

        myEquipment[18] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings, ItemType.Beginner_Leggings);
        myEquipment[19] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings, ItemType.Cloth_Leggings);
        myEquipment[20] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings, ItemType.Wooden_Leggings);
        myEquipment[21] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings, ItemType.Iron_Leggings);
        myEquipment[22] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings, ItemType.Frost_Leggings);
        myEquipment[23] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings, ItemType.Magma_Leggings);

        myEquipment[24] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots, ItemType.Beginner_Boots);
        myEquipment[25] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots, ItemType.Cloth_Boots);
        myEquipment[26] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots, ItemType.Wooden_Boots);
        myEquipment[27] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots, ItemType.Iron_Boots);
        myEquipment[28] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots, ItemType.Frost_Boots);
        myEquipment[29] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots, ItemType.Magma_Boots);

        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[0] , passingvalues[0]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[1] , passingvalues[1]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[2] , passingvalues[2]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[3] , passingvalues[3]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[4] , passingvalues[4]);

        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[5] , passingvalues[5]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[6] , passingvalues[6]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[7] , passingvalues[7]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[8] , passingvalues[8]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[9] , passingvalues[9]);

        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[10] , passingvalues[10]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[11] , passingvalues[11]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[12] , passingvalues[12]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[13] , passingvalues[13]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[14] , passingvalues[14]);

        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[15] , passingvalues[15]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[16] , passingvalues[16]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[17] , passingvalues[17]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[18] , passingvalues[18]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[19] , passingvalues[19]);

        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[20] , passingvalues[20]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[21] , passingvalues[21]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[22] , passingvalues[22]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[23] , passingvalues[23]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[24] , passingvalues[24]);

        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[25] , passingvalues[25]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[26] , passingvalues[26]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[27] , passingvalues[27]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[28] , passingvalues[28]);
        EquipmentList.addObject(myEquipment[29] , passingvalues[29]);

    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test-Rig
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        Player player = new Player();
        player.displayObject();


        /**
        EquipmentMap EquipmentList = new EquipmentMap(); 
        Equipment equipment = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword,ItemType.Beginner_Sword);
        Integer i[] = {20,10};
        EquipmentList.addObject(equipment, i);
        Equipment equip = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword,ItemType.Beginner_Sword);
        Integer j[] = EquipmentList.getObject(equip);
        System.out.println(j[0] + "/" + j[1]);
        */
    }

}


package Default;
import Default.EquipmentType;

public class Equipment
{

    private EquipmentType eEquipmentType;
    private ItemType eItem;

    public Equipment(EquipmentType EquipmentType, ItemType ItemType)
    {
        setEquipmentType(EquipmentType);
        reset();
        setItem(ItemType);
    }

    public Equipment(EquipmentType EquipmentType)
    {
        setEquipmentType(EquipmentType);
        reset();
    }

    //item ids are as follows
    //Sword: 10-19 
    //Helmet: 20-29    
    //Chestplate: 30-39
    //Leggings: 40-49
    //Boots: 50-59

    //0 sword, 1 helmet, 2 chestplate, 3 leggings, 4 boots
    public void setEquipmentType(EquipmentType EquipmentType)
    {
        this.eEquipmentType = EquipmentType; 
    }

    public void setItem(ItemType Item)
    {
        this.eItem = Item;
    }

    public EquipmentType getEquipmentType()
    {
        return( this.eEquipmentType );  
    }

    public ItemType getItem()
    {
        return( this.eItem );
    }

    private void reset()
    {
        switch(getEquipmentType())
        {
            case Sword:
            setItem(ItemType.Beginner_Sword);
            break;

            case Helmet:
            setItem(ItemType.Beginner_Helmet);
            break;

            case Chestplate:
            setItem(ItemType.Beginner_Chestplate);
            break;

            case Leggings:
            setItem(ItemType.Beginner_Leggings);
            break;

            case Boots:
            setItem(ItemType.Beginner_Boots);
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {



    }

}



package Default;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class EquipmentMap 
{

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Class Variables
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Map<Equipment, Integer[]> EquipmentMap;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    EquipmentMap()
    {
        EquipmentMap = new HashMap < Equipment , Integer[] > ();
        return;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Setters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void addObject( Object Equipment , Integer[] i)
    {
        EquipmentMap.put( ( Default.Equipment ) Equipment , i ) ;
        return ;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Getters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public Integer[] getObject( Object Equipment )
    {
        Integer[] i = EquipmentMap.get( ( Default.Equipment ) Equipment ) ;
        return ( i ) ;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test-Rig
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {



    }

}



package Default;

public enum ArmourStatType 
{
    Power(0), Hitpoints(1);
    private int iValue;

    private ArmourStatType( int Value )
    {
        this.iValue = Value ;
        return ;
    }

    // access method
    public int getValue()
    {
        return ( this.iValue ) ;
    }

}



package Default;

public enum WeaponStatType 
{
    Power(0), CritChance(1);
    private int iValue;

    private WeaponStatType( int Value )
    {
        this.iValue = Value ;
        return ;
    }

    // access method
    public int getValue()
    {
        return ( this.iValue ) ;
    }

}



package Default;

public enum BaseStatType 
{
    Strength(0), Protection(1), Vitality(2);
    private int iValue;

    private BaseStatType( int Value )
    {
        this.iValue = Value ;
        return ;
    }

    // access method
    public int getValue()
    {
        return ( this.iValue ) ;
    }

}



package Default;

public enum StatType 
{
    Attack(0), Defence(1), Hitpoints(2);
    private int iValue;

    private StatType( int Value )
    {
        this.iValue = Value ;
        return ;
    }

    // access method
    public int getValue()
    {
        return ( this.iValue ) ;
    }

}



package Default;

public enum ItemType 
{
        Beginner_Sword(10), 
        Beginner_Helmet(20), 
        Beginner_Chestplate(30),
        Beginner_Leggings(40),
        Beginner_Boots(50),
        Cloth_Sword(11),
        Cloth_Helmet(21),
        Cloth_Chestplate(31),
        Cloth_Leggings(41),
        Cloth_Boots(51),
        Wooden_Sword(12),
        Wooden_Helmet(22),
        Wooden_Chestplate(32),
        Wooden_Leggings(42),
        Wooden_Boots(52),
        Iron_Sword(13),
        Iron_Helmet(23),
        Iron_Chestplate(33),
        Iron_Leggings(43),
        Iron_Boots(53),
        Frost_Sword(14),
        Frost_Helmet(24),
        Frost_Chestplate(34),
        Frost_Leggings(44),
        Frost_Boots(54),
        Magma_Sword(15),
        Magma_Helmet(25),
        Magma_Chestplate(35),
        Magma_Leggings(45),
        Magma_Boots(55);

        private int iID;

        private ItemType( int ID )
        {
            this.iID = ID ;
            return ;
        }

        // access method
        public int getValue()
        {
            return ( this.iID ) ;
        }

    }


package Default;

public enum IVType 
{
    Strength(0), Protection(1), Vitality(2);
    private int iValue;

    private IVType( int Value )
    {
        this.iValue = Value ;
        return ;
    }

    // access method
    public int getValue()
    {
        return ( this.iValue ) ;
    }

}
```

Expected result should be the reset correctly functions and the calculation in getPlayerHitpoints can go ahead due to the return of the Integer[].

This is the error message: https://gyazo.com/d509055b1d7e5d55386cbee684ac3531

Comment: There is TOO much code, Please provide a minimal and reproducible example

Comment: `EquipmentType` is not given, the error line is not pointed in the code, in the error method you always write to [0] to overwrite your content, seems that's unclear for you even if there is lot of code, or it's not your code ?

Comment: Ok, spend 10min, too much code, good luck ;)

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 0):

as @azro already pointed out, the problem is with your

```java
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Sword , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Sword) );
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Helmet , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Helmet) );
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Chestplate) );
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Leggings , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Leggings) );
        eMyEquipment[0] = new Equipment(EquipmentType.Boots , getMyEquipment(EquipmentType.Boots) );
```

part of the code. As you can see in for example the `private void reset()` method, you need to count up  the numbers ranging von 0 to 4. These wrong numbers lead to the `null` instead of your desired Integer[].
Hope this helps, cheers